# Android HorizontalScrollView width

Tags: android, xml, layout, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

This is my XML of the `HorizontalScrollView`

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="19" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/card_background" >

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

I want to set the width of the RelativeLayout equal to the width of the HorizontalScrollView. How can I do this with XML (not programmatically)

Comment: set RelativeLayout parent LinearLayout width as match_parent...

Answer (score 11):

All you are missing for what you want is in the HorizontalScrollView

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Comment: It didn't change anything , because I have a linearlayout in my scrollview which has `width="wrap_content"`

Comment: without the rest of the layout the only problem i had other than not having the fillViewport setting was the 0dp because i tested with the horizontalScrollView has the root element. If you change the 0dp to match_parent it fills the entire screen.
Maybe if you provide de entire layout we can help further...

Comment: Now it works fine , but another problem occurred . When I add views to my ScrollView I can scroll it normally

Comment: *I can't scroll it :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd define the width you want to set to the `RelativeLayout` and set the `HorizontalScrollView`'s width and height to `wrap_content`. This way it's not the `HorizontalScrollView` who's defining the width, it just wrap it.

Comment: I want my RelativeLayout to take all the width of the screen . In that case I cant set it to match_parent , because the parent of my RelativeLayout is a LinearLayout

Comment: Then I'd add another RelativeLayout above the HorizontalScrollView, set its width to match_parent, and then declare the HorizontalScrollView with the width set to wrap_content, this way you know it will be all the width long and the scroller will wrap it all.